# How to set value for ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
$scope.payin = [{ value: 1.00 }, { value: 2.00 },{ value: 3.00 }, { value: 5.00 }];
```

and i have

```
  <select class="pull-right form-control" ng-model="pay" ng-options="p.value for p in payin" value="{{p.value}}">{{p.value}}</select>
```

but in my dropdown list first value is empty string... i want to be 1,2,3,5 and not "",1,2,3,5

Comment: What Raulucco said below. If you don't set the value then angular will automatically add an empty value item to the dropdown

Comment: i get empty string on first place again

Comment: If model is not set, i.e. `$scope.pay` is `undefined` then angular will add an empty option in the select.

Comment: i get object in $scope.pay so its not undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ng-model value otherwise angular will add a null value.

There is also a problem with your select. You shouldn't be setting value :

```
$scope.payin = [{ value: 1.00 }, { value: 2.00 },{ value: 3.00 }, { value: 5.00 }];
$scope.pay = $scope.payin[0];
```

```
<select class="pull-right form-control" ng-model="pay" ng-options="p.value for p in payin"></select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IWXkl5ozliCQ51IQoFn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the first value to be selected by default on your controller. Just after you load the paying array

```
$scope.pay = $scope.payin[0];
```

Comment: actually i get empty string again

Comment: Yes I wrote paying instead of payin. As I thought it is a typo

Comment: is there any other way to do this because its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<select class="pull-right form-control" ng-model="pay" ng-options="p.value for p in payin" value="{{p.value}}">{{p.value}}
       <option style="display:none" value=""></option>
      </select>
```

Comment: You are still getting empty string in 1st option.?